# how to get updated Viewchildren reference after sorting in angular MatTable

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material, mat-table

I am working on angular material table and want to get tableRow reference using `ViewChildren` and `ViewContainerRef`.

Here Html Snippet

`<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" #tableRows ></tr>`

and TS snippet

`@ViewChildren('tableRows', {read: ViewContainerRef}) rowContainers`

I am able to get table rows refrence but problem is that when I sort, I am not able to get updated DOM reference in `rowContainers` variables.

I couldn't find any way to refresh `rowContainers` variable.

Does anybody have idea how to refresh `ViewChildren` variable ?

You can see behavior in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-viewcontainerref) .

Comment: Normally you could subscribe to the `changes` Observable of the `QueryList` that is produced by `@ViewChildren`, which should then emit the changes once the list has changed but this does not to seem to work as it emits the unordered list of rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I supouse you want the first element of the array, not the ViewChildren.
Susbcribe to rowContainers.changes, not work, but, as you're using a MatTableDataSource, you always can use its methond _orderData (that need an array of element), e.g., you can write some like

```
let orderData=this.dataSource._orderData(this.dataSource.data)
console.log(orderData[0])
```

**Update**
If we want order the ViewChildren we need pass the viewChildren to array, sort the array and make a reset. If our viewChildren are "ViewContainerRef"

```
@ViewChildren('tableRows', {read: ViewContainerRef}) rowContainers: QueryList<any>
//We can access to the content using, e.g.
 rowContainers.first.element.nativeElement.textContent;
```

If our ViewChildren are "ElementRef"

```
@ViewChildren('tableRows', {read: ElementRef}) rowContainers: QueryList<any>
//We can access to the content using, e.g.
 rowContainers.first.nativeElement.textContent;
```

So, when we make a click

```
  rowClick(table:any) {
    //get the order data
    const orderData=this.dataSource._orderData(this.dataSource.data);
    //convert rowContainers to array
    const array=this.rowContainers.toArray();
    //sort the array
    array.sort((a,b)=>{
      //the content of "a" and "b"
      //e.g. will be " 3 Lithium 6.941 Li"
      let contentA=a.element.nativeElement.textContent;
      let contentB=b.element.nativeElement.textContent;
      //get the index in our orderData
      let indexA=orderData.findIndex(d=>''+d.position==contentA.split(' ')[1])
      let indexB=orderData.findIndex(d=>''+d.position==contentB.split(' ')[1])
      //return 0 if equal, 1 if greater, -1 if less
      return indexA==indexB?0:indexA>indexB?1:-1;
    })
    //make a reset
    this.rowContainers.reset(array);
    console.log(this.rowContainers.first.element.nativeElement.textContent);
    this.firstElement = this.rowContainers.first;
  }
```

**Update2**
If we has the table as ViewChild

```
@ViewChild(MatTable, {read:ElementRef}) table
```

We can use its nativeElement.textContent, so

```
  rowClick(table:any) {
    const array=this.rowContainers.toArray();

    //using context the table
    const tableArray=this.table.nativeElement.textContent.split(' ')
    let order:any[]=[]

    for (let i=9;i<tableArray.length;i+=8)
       order.push(tableArray[i])

    array.sort((a,b)=>{
      let contentA=a.element.nativeElement.textContent;
      let contentB=b.element.nativeElement.textContent;
      let indexA=order.findIndex(d=>d==contentA.split(' ')[1])
      let indexB=order.findIndex(d=>d==contentB.split(' ')[1])
      return indexA==indexB?0:indexA>indexB?1:-1;
    })
    this.rowContainers.reset(array);
    console.log(this.rowContainers.first.element.nativeElement.textContent);
    this.firstElement = this.rowContainers.first;
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-viewcontainerref-s21h2y?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: No, I don't want data. I want updated dom reference for which I am using ViewChildren.

Comment: To "reorder" ViewChildren, you first pass to array, reorder the array and use reset https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#reset :myArray=myQueryList.toArray();..reorder array..;myQueryList.reset(myArray)

Comment: If you want, e.g. add a class to the first, you can get the first element and use [ngStyle] or [style.attribute]

Comment: I tried reset approach but it didn't work. I updated stackblitz.

Comment: Thanks, although your solution is working...but I was thinking if it can be done by angular api only.